# How to solve particular solution of a general differential equation involving $\cos^3 x$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

My question was to solve,
$(D^2 +2D +5) y= e^x \cos^3 x. \space$
I solved complementary function solution but got stuck in solving particular solution. I am attaching my solution where I stuck, please help me to solve it. Thanks a lot. [Image of question and my attempt to solve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3tl5.jpg)

Comment: Typeset mathematical terms using MathJax rather than posting images. [Here's the tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Thanks a lot for informing me sir, I am trying my best to edit the question in prescribed format. I am new to it, sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: **Hint:** Your complementary solution looks correct. Make the substitution  $$e^x \cos ^3(x) = \dfrac{1}{4} e^x (3 \cos (x)+\cos (3 x))$$ Try $$y_p(x) = e^x(a \cos x + b \sin x + c \cos 3x + d \sin 3x)$$

Comment: @Moo sir Thanks , I was able to solve it by using $cos^3x=1/4(cos(3x) + 3cos(x)) $ and then using $cos(x) = real part\ e^{ix}$

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to MSE.

$\displaystyle cos(x) = \frac{e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}{2} \tag{1}$

$\displaystyle (a+b)^3 = a^3 + 3a^2b + 3ab^2 + b^3\tag{2}$

$\displaystyle \cos^3(x) = \frac1{8} \left( e^{i3x} + 3e^{ix} + 3e^{-ix} + e^{-i3x} \right) = \frac1{4}\cos(3x) + \frac{3}{4}\cos(x) \tag{3}$

For $e^xcos^3(x)$ first try $y = ce^{mx}$ where $m \in \Bbb C$ for the particular solution to:

$(D^2 +2D +5) y= e^{mx} \tag{4}$

$m^2ce^{mx} + 2mce^{mx} + 5ce^{mx} = e^{mx} \tag{5}$

$m^2c + 2mc + 5c = 1 \tag{6}$

$\displaystyle c = \frac1{m^2 + 2m + 5} \tag{7}$

$\displaystyle e^xcos^3(x) = \frac1{8}e^{(1+i3)x} + \frac{3}{8}e^{(1+i)x} + \frac{3}{8}e^{(1-i)x} + \frac1{8}e^{(1-i3)x} \tag{8}$

The $m$ values are $1+i3,1+i,1-i,1-i3$ from which to calculate the $c$ values for $y = ce^{mx}$

The rest is algebra and grouping of conjugates to arrive at a real solution.

Maxima:

```
dd(x) := expand(x^2 + 2*x + 5);

c(x) := conjugate(dd(x))/(expand(dd(x)*conjugate(dd(x))));

y : 1/8*e^((1+3*%i)*x)*c(1+3*%i) + 1/8*e^((1-3*%i)*x)*c(1-3*%i)  + 3/8*e^((1+%i)*x)*c(1+%i) + 3/8*e^((1-%i)*x)*c(1-%i);

expand(y);
```

$$y _p = -{{3\,i\,e^{3\,i\,x+x}}\over{290}}-{{e^{3\,i\,x+x}}\over{1160}}-{{3
 \,i\,e^{i\,x+x}}\over{130}}+{{21\,e^{i\,x+x}}\over{520}}+{{3\,i\,e^{
 x-i\,x}}\over{130}}+{{21\,e^{x-i\,x}}\over{520}}+{{3\,i\,e^{x-3\,i\,
 x}}\over{290}}-{{e^{x-3\,i\,x}}\over{1160}} \tag{9}$$

In this case you can group them by the denominators:

$$y _p = 
-\frac{3\,ie^x}{290}\,\left(e^{3\,i\,x} - e^{-3\,i\,x}\right)
-\frac{e^x}{1160}\left({e^{3\,i\,x}} + e^{-3\,i\,x}\right)
-\frac{3ie^x}{130} \left(e^{i\,x} - e^{-i\,x}\right)
+\frac{21 e^x}{520} \left(e^{i\,x} + e^{-i\,x} \right)
\tag{10}$$

$$y _p = 
\frac{3e^x}{145}\,\sin({3\,x})
-\frac{e^x}{580}\cos(3\,x)
 + \frac{3e^x}{65} \sin(x)
+\frac{21 e^x}{260} \cos(x)
\tag{11}$$

sanity check, Maxima:

```
yp : 3/145*%e^x*sin(3*x) -%e^x/580*cos(3*x) + 3/65*%e^x*sin(x) + 21/260*%e^x*cos(x);

expand(diff(yp,x,2) + 2*diff(yp,x,1) + 5*yp);
```

$${{e^{x}\,\cos \left(3\,x\right)}\over{4}}+{{3\,e^{x}\,\cos x}\over{4}} \tag{12}$$

From $(3)$:

$$e^x \cos ^3(x) = {{e^{x}\,\cos \left(3\,x\right)}\over{4}}+{{3\,e^{x}\,\cos x}\over{4}}$$

So $(11)$ is the particular solution.

Comment: If you can see the trick use it. If not the exponential method could be more generally useful.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I was able to solve it by using $cos^3x=1/4(cos(3x) + 3cos(x)) $ and then using $cos(x) = real part\ e^(ix) $